# How efficient smart pointers are?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, std

I know, that `std::shared_ptr` uses reference counting, so it has copy&move semantics, on the other hand `std::unique_ptr` (hence the name unique) only has move semantics, so trying to copy it is a compile error.

However, its not quite clear for me how big of a deal is that. Can I simply use `std::shared_ptr` over `std::unique_ptr` in most cases, or should I use `std::unique_ptr` whenever possible, as it's far more efficient because it doesn't have to take care of reference counting?

Also, I know that smart pointers are useful when dealing with, for example exception safety, but are they a mean to generally replace traditional `T*` pointers? 
Is it a good programming practice to use smart pointers over traditional `T*` pointers whenever possible?

Comment: You should only use `shared_ptr` if you need shared ownership. If not, there is no reason to use it.

Comment: It's not a question of _efficiency_, but _semantics_.

Comment: Those are two different questions, but to answer your second: I do mostly use smart pointer, when possible.

Comment: Owning raw pointers should never be used. Whether you use a non-owning raw pointer or something like [`std::experimental::observer_ptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf) is more of a matter of style.

Comment: @juanchopanza Strangely, the majority of uses for `shared_ptr` in my code end up being mostly `weak_ptr` based, where I want decoupled notification of destruction of some token to change some other behavior.  No *real* shared ownership, just an easy decoupled death-notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule of thumb is:

1. If you can, use a stack based object directly or by a reference instead of using pointers.
2. Else, if you don't have to deal with shared ownership (usually you don't) use unique_ptr - it is not only faster, but also safer (no circular references).
3. Else, if you do have shared ownership, use shared_ptr

Raw pointers are OK in certain circumstances when they don't carry ownership - for instance as an input argument to a function:

```
void draw (const shape* sh) {
    sh->draw();
}

...
std::unique_ptr<shape> ptr(new triangle);
draw(ptr.get());
```

Comment: `unique_ptr` may also leak because of circular reference: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G7GM1xjbe

Comment: Your `draw` example is better off using a reference unless `sh` is optionally null.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the `shared_ptr` is, that, afaik, the reference counting is an atomic function, that means it not only counts the references, but also has locking functionality to ensure that the function is atomic. So at that point, yes, `unique_ptr` is better to use, when you only need move functionality.

Personally, I dont use `shared_ptr` alot, mostly normal pointers are enough. Imho smart pointers are only encourage getting lazy in memory management. I was in projects where smart pointers only caused race conditions when quitting the program, because nobody knew the order of destruction and these pointers referenced each others. For myself, I only use them if a lib of mine is putting pointers to the outside for which it is irrelevent when they get deleted (or in which order).

Comment: Right, though a minor clarification: AFAIR atomics on most platforms are implemented as some kind of CAS-like operations (Interlocked*() functions in Windows-speak), so performance impact, while it exists (on x86 it is a some kind of instruction with LOCK prefix), cannot cause a context switch (as it would if they implement atomics via mutexes). In other words, penalty of atomics is on the order of 100 clocks, and not 10000 clocks as it might be in case of mutexes/critical sections.

Comment: You are right in that point, thanks for correcting me. I would have to look at the implementation of the pointers, which I dont have the time at the moment. Either way, if you really want to be as performant as possible (e.g. realtime operations), then you should only use smart pointers when really needed.

Comment: I have to disagree with the advice to avoid using smart pointers of any kind. You might not need `shared_ptr` everywhere or might not accept the potential performance hit but in that case you should always reach for `unique_ptr`. The community has come down heavily on the side of `new` and `delete` being essentially deprecated. Of course raw pointers and references to objects managed to smart pointers are still fine *so long as you can guarantee that their lifetime will not extend that of the smart pointer* which is admittedly a difficult thing to do in C++.

Comment: Ive never propagated to avoid them at any cost. I put up one scernario where it would be better to ditch them. Ther other thing I said was, that **I** dont use them alot. Smart pointers are a good thing, no question. But also i have to disagree that `new` and `delete` are deprecated. I have many cases where I do not see any benefit of a raw pointer over a `unique_ptr`, which does not mean there are no such cases. Of course, raw pointers are in some case harder to handle and you should be aware of that. But you also must be aware that `weak_ptr` can break the benefits of `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer values to `std::unique_ptr`, and `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` whenever possible, but not for performance reasons. Yes, there is some overhead when it comes to `std::shared_ptr`, as they use inside some form of atomic counter, but this is negligible for most applications.

The main reason to use `std::unique_ptr` is the uniqueness semantics - when you (or someone else) read(s) the code it's very clear the lifetime and the ownership of the object. This makes it more easy to reason about the code and find logical/performance issues.

PS: `std::unique_ptr` has no overhead compared to raw pointer, but it has some great advantages.

Answer (score 0):

A shared_ptr has the extra cost of construction/destruction of the pointer itself, if passed to a function, plus the reference counting mechanism.

Do not listen to anyone that says either smart pointers are always the way to go, nor to people who say raw pointers are always better. 
There are cases where smart pointers make sense, and cases where raw pointers are preferable.

For a more detailed and comprehensive read, I'll suggest you to visit:
http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

It covers all the points you raised and it is an easy read for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` means that the ownership rules surrounding the resource are complicated.  Understanding them requires tracking down the lifetime of all `shared_ptr`s in the general case.

`unique_ptr` means that the ownership rules surrounding the resource are dead easy.

Both enforce a set of ownership rules, but the rules for `unique_ptr` are simple and local, the rules for `shared_ptr` are complex and non-local.  If you are in a situation where you are choosing between the two casually, then you aren't treating lifetime issues with the gravity they deserve.

If you have a pointer-like resource whose lifetime should be controlled simply, or even at some central location (type-wise) with complex logic around it, use `unique_ptr`.  The cost over a raw pointer is minimal, and it adds (enforced) documentation that this is the "owning" pointer to this resource.

If you *must* have a resource whose lifetime is the union of the lifetime of a bunch of other objects, all of whom have unrelated lifetimes, `shared_ptr` can be considered.  If your situation is so complex that a loop could possibly be formed, then naive `shared_ptr` use is no longer a practical option.

`shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` can also be used as a distributed lifetime notification system, where a central location stores a (mostly unique) `shared_ptr`, and clients store `weak_ptr`s.  Local (non-stored) `shared_ptr`s are created from the `weak_ptr`s in order to check that the target resource still exists, then the resource is manipulated, then the local `shared_ptr` is discarded.  The goal here is to make (in a non-language enforced way) a `unique_ptr` with weak shares, so reasoning about lifetime is only marginally harder than the `unique_ptr` case.

`shared_ptr` basically *never* "solves" the lifetime problem without you proving that it will solve your lifetime problems.  It can make some parts of that proof marginally easier.